# Error installing Laravel 5.2 on forge

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, forge

I am trying to resolve this error, and looking for answer everywhere. I checked and they are all enabled in ini file, and it's giving me error.

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for sabre/xml dev-master -> satisfiable by sabre/xml[dev-master].
    - sabre/xml dev-master requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

```
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zlib.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was facing the same issue after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04 which by default comes with php7. I was able to resolve it by running the following commands
Run the update comand:

```
      sudo apt-get update
```

They mycript is missing and needs to be installed:

```
      sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
```

Run the upgrade command:

```
      sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install the php-mbstring which is also missing:

```
     sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Install the phpunit which is also missing:

```
     sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

And it worked.